# How to properly superimpose weather radar data on map

Tags: mapbox, weather

I am trying to superimpose weather radar data onto a map.  It needs to be done programmatically as this will be part of a program (python) that displays weather data.  It is *not* browser based, and will be running on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

The radar data I am trying to use comes from NOAA (examples https://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/RIDGEII/L2/KLWX/BREF_RAW/).  They are GeoTIFF files with 4 bands (RGBA).

For maps, I am using static maps from [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com), but I am open to other suggestions.  I am downloading a map with a specific bounding box that matches the radar image's bounding box.  e.g.  [https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/[-82.487,33.976,-72.487,43.976]/1024x1024?access_token=xxxxx](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/%5B-82.487,33.976,-72.487,43.976%5D/1024x1024?access_token=xxxxx).  That gives me a PNG image.

I tried a simplistic approach of scaling the map to be the same size as the radar data, and then just overlaying them.  But that put the radar data in the wrong location (about 50 miles off based on what radar.weather.gov was displaying at the time I downloaded the latest radar image).

So as a test, I tried georeferencing the map like

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -82.487 43.976 -72.487 33.976 -a_srs EPSG:4326 map.png map.tiff
```

and loading both it and the radar in qgis, but the radar data looks like it is in the wrong location: the same wrong location I got with a simple overlay.

So what am I doing wrong?

What I want is....

1. get map that matches radar images
2. overlay the radar onto the map (with some transparency)

EDIT:

This is what I am getting
[image: What I get]

This is a screen capture from radar.weather.gov at the same time I downloaded the weather radar file.  The rain band near Pittsburg is clearly in a different position, then what I got.
[image: screen capture from radar.weather.gov]

I can't upload the radar GeoTIFF here as it is too big (2579856 bytes) so I put it https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmsj9ljz6kkivsu/KLWX_L2_BREF_RAW_20220607_230449.tif?dl=0

EDIT

Is the real problem related to mapbox not giving me the map I asked for?  If I add markers to google maps of the 4 corners specified by the bounding box I asked mapbox for, they are at different locations then the corners of the mapbox map.  north/South look somewhat close, but East/West really different.

Google maps with pins at 4 corners of bounding box.
[image: googlemap with bbox corners marked]

Map downloaded from Mapbox via [https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/[-82.487,33.976,-72.487,43.976]/1024x1024?access_token=xxxxx](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/%5B-82.487,33.976,-72.487,43.976%5D/1024x1024?access_token=xxxxx)

[image: map as downloaded from mapbox]

Comment: please add a picture of what the output shows

Comment: The PNG from mapbox is likely to be in EPSG:3857 (web mercator) square pixels. Your TIFF is in lat-long square pixels. You need a non-linear stretch to make them overlap correctly, not a simple scaling. That might be the problem. The TIFF seems correctly georeferenced when loaded into QGIS (which does proper raster projection transforms). Try gdaltransform of one of the rasters, but you'll also have to crop to get exactly overlaying rectangular rasters (because transform will warp to non-rectangular with padding)

Comment: ^^`gdalwarp` not `gdaltransform`

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I tried  echo gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:3857 -a_ullr $ullr map.png map-3857.tiff; gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:4326 map-3857.tiff map-4326.tiff and that put the map in the wrong location.  gdalinfo had the origin at  (-0.000740993328412,0.000395043129336).   I tried moving it with gdalwarp -te -82.487 33.976 -72.487 43.976 -ts 1024 1024 map-4326.tiff map-4326a.tiff, and that moved it, but I just got a black box.